# how to get all text from uitextfield in uitableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a table view with a UITextField in each cell.the table has 30 lines。
i want to get all values from 30 UITextfield，But it works fine for 10 visible cells. I cant't access any invisible cells. the text returns null. please help me.I am a chese developer

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code for your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method?  Also, what's a cheese developer?  Is it related to Cheddar?

Answer (score 0):

> I cant't access any invisible cells. the text returns null.

That's how it is supposed to work since `UITableView` optimizes its use of cells and only displayed cells are actually existing at any time. (at least, if you are using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` as you will find in most UITableView tutorials).

You should possibly store the text entered by the user in each table row somewhere (in your model?) and then access it from there.

Alternatively, you could avoid using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` but in that case you should manage the set of cells in the table view on your own. (I am not encouraging your to do this, it's just a possibility).

Comment: If I don't use the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier,How to write the code？

Comment: You should do the same as in the other case. E.g., ad an NSMutableArray as property in your controller and store in there the cells (or the user content, much better). Then you iterate over the array to get all the cells/user content.